# Correct way of using elasticsearch with DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am using a test example of elastic search here the link of docs https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/0.1.8/quick_start.html with django rest.

I did the same as the docs did but it is not working on the case of mine. In addition, in the docs run the server on 8000 port if I am running the server with this port `Connection error failed` error throws but If I run on 9200 port it works but it returns 404 in the image shown below

[image]

here is my code:

**book.py**

```
@BOOK_INDEX.doc_type
@registry.register_document
class BookDocument(Document):
    """Book Elasticsearch document."""

    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    title = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    description = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    summary = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    publisher = fields.TextField(
        attr='publisher_indexing',
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    publication_date = fields.DateField()

    state = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    isbn = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword'
            )
        }
    )

    price = fields.FloatField()

    pages = fields.IntegerField()

    stock_count = fields.IntegerField()

    tags = fields.TextField(
        attr='tags_indexing',
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(
                analyzer='keyword',
                multi=True
            )
        },
        multi=True
    )

    class Django:
        """Meta options."""

        model = Book  # The model associate with this DocType
```

**views.py**

```
class BookDocumentView(DocumentViewSet):
    """The BookDocument view."""

    document = BookDocument
    serializer_class = BookDocumentSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        IdsFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        SearchFilterBackend,
    ]
    # Define search fields
    search_fields = (
        'title',
        'description',
        'summary',
    )
    # Define filter fields
    filter_fields = {
        'id': {
            'field': 'id',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of id field in this example,
            # to `range`, `in`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },
        'title': 'title.raw',
        'publisher': 'publisher.raw',
        'publication_date': 'publication_date',
        'state': 'state.raw',
        'isbn': 'isbn.raw',
        'price': {
            'field': 'price.raw',
            # Note, that we limit the lookups of `price` field in this
            # example, to `range`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt` and `lte` filters.
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        }...
```

please can anybody help me with this issue? In general Am I doing right to run the server on 9200 port? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with python but if its a port issue then FYI: ES default port is 9200 and your app port should be diff and your app should connect to ES and get the result, you can also check ES results by hitting their api on 9200 port

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have no indexes. Execute the command **python manage.py search_index --rebuild** to create your indexes.